# Get the value of a table cell in javascript with external script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple table filled with rows from a MySQL database, the HTML part looks like this

```
  <tbody>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
    <tr class="rows" id="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">  // the id is an auto incremented int
      <td id="col1"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
      <td id="col2"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
      <td id="col3"><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
      <td id="col4"><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
      <td id="col5"><?php echo $row[5]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
```

It gets the job done and I have a nice table. Now I want that if I click on a row, i get five variables with the values of the cells.

The problem what stopped me was to get the `<td>` element. This is what I tried in the external javascript file:

```
var rows    = document.getElementsByClassName('rows');
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    rows[i].onclick = function(){
        console.log(this.getElementById('col1')); // I tried to print it first
    }
}
```

The console responded this: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Then I tried `console.log(rows[i].getElementById(vonalkod));`, but it responded `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined`

If I only write `console.log(this);` then it prints what I expect, the whole row in html.

So my question is that what is the syntax to get those cells by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to get the contents of a cell is

```
document.getElementById('col1').innerHTML
```

Now, having said that, it will only work if you have ONE `col1`: if you have more than one of these `<tr>`s each will have five `td`s like `<td id=col1>`, the same for the rest of the id-s. That's invalid HTML. Consider replacing those id-s with classes, or with additional PHP.

---

Or, better yet, you can forgo all these clumsy `id`-s entirely and use something like:

```
rows[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.childNodes[0].innerHTML); // col1
    console.log(this.childNodes[1].innerHTML); // col2
    // ... etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing my duplicated ID-s, and you're right, I should have used childNotes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the object *this* is a *HTMLTableRowElement*  (see http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/html2/HTMLTableRowElement.html)

Here a library as jQuery comes very handy. Your script written using jQuery is as easy as

```
jQuery('.rows').click(function(){
    alert(jQuery(this).children('#col1').text());
});
```

Comment: Well, it turns out my biggest problem was that I didn't know what the _this_ object was. Thank you for the useful information.

Comment: @nandoo you definetely need to use a debugger such as the one built-in developer tools of Chrome. You can open developer tools, go to the row where everything is breaking, set a breakpoint and add to the watchlist to the right "this" and click the element with the handler. There you'll know everything about your variables